# jsprf.c:644: error: incompatible types in assignment

Tags: spidermonkey, nspr

Can you help me with this error I encountered while building 
Spidermonkey in PPC?

```
make -f Makefile.ref cat: ../../dist/Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/nspr/Version: 
No such file or directory 
cd editline; make -f Makefile.ref all 
make[1]: Entering directory `/units/ 
spidermonkey-1.8-next-wip/src/editline' 
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'. 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/units/ 
spidermonkey-1.8-next-wip/src/editline' 
make -f Makefile.ref  Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/libjs.a Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/ 
libjs.so Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/js  Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/jsautocfg.h 
Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/jscpucfg Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/jscpucfg.o 
cat: ../../dist/Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/nspr/Version: No such file or 
directory 
make[1]: Entering directory `/units/ 
spidermonkey-1.8-next-wip/src' 
make[1]: Circular jscpucfg.h <- Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/jsautocfg.h 
dependency dropped. 
make[1]: Circular Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/jsautocfg.h <- Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/ 
jsautocfg.h dependency dropped. 
/powerpc-750- 
linux-gnu_gcc-3.4.6/bin/powerpc-750-linux-gnu-gcc -o Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/ 
jsprf.o -c -Wall -Wno-format -MMD -DGCC_OPT_BUG -g3 -DXP_UNIX -DSVR4 - 
DSYSV -D_BSD_SOURCE -DPOSIX_SOURCE -DHAVE_LOCALTIME_R -DX86_LINUX  - 
DDEBUG -DDEBUG_build -DEDITLINE -ILinux_All_DBG.OBJ  jsprf.c 
jsprf.c: In function `BuildArgArray': 
jsprf.c:644: error: incompatible types in assignment 
make[1]: *** [Linux_All_DBG.OBJ/jsprf.o] Error 1 
make[1]: Leaving directory `/units/ 
spidermonkey-1.8-next-wip/src' 
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm using a Redhat-Linux machine.

Do I need to have NSPR too to cross-compile spidermonkey?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Did you actually look at the source code to see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Fix is here:
http://github.com/janl/couchdbx-core/blob/ff47372552d10df00d74cb7989dfed4a19a6040d/patches/js/patch-jsprf.c

BR
villem